# This sense of mutual interaction

Tags: word-meaning

Source: Sport and Exercise Psychology: A Critical Introduction — Aidan Moran

> In everyday life, we tend to see any collection of people as a group. However, social psychologists use this term more precisely. In particular, they define a group as two or more people who interact with, and exert mutual influences on, each other (Aronson, Wilson and Akert, 2002). It is this **sense** of mutual interaction or inter-dependence for a common purpose which distinguishes the members of a group from a mere aggregation of individuals.

---

I don't think that "**sense**" mean "*meaning*". I think that it doesn't fit the context.
Does "**sense**" mean "*idea*" or does it mean
"*feeling*"?

Comment: Sense --> **meaning**. See [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sense) *one of the possible meanings of a word or phrase*.

Comment: @WeatherVane It seems to me that the "**sense**" means "*concept*", not "*meaning*". What do you think about that?

Comment: Two or more people interacting isn't a concept, although they might formulate a concept in their interaction.

Comment: @WeatherVane I suspect that "**sense**" here means "perception", not "meaning". Members of a group perceive themselves as being interdependent and as sharing interactions. I wonder what you think about that.

Comment: Again the group might have perception, but IMO it isn't the meaning of 'sense' here. The group has a common purpose, not just a random chat.

Comment: The quotation mentions a group of people in a productive discussion. That group is neither a concept or a perception (although it might have such). Is is an *example* of a group which has a higher purpose than conversational chat.

Comment: @WeatherVane I have one more question. I wonder what "**it**" refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with comments claiming that ***sense*** in the cited text means ***meaning***. If that were the case, it would be completely unnecessary to include the words ***this sense of*** at all...

> 1: *It<sup>1</sup> is **mutual interaction or inter-dependence for a common purpose** which distinguishes the members of a group from a mere aggregation of individuals.*

...which can be simplified and rephrased to...

> 2: ***Mutual interaction** distinguishes the members of a group from a mere aggregation of individuals.*

I find that perfectly valid as it stands, but we can *explicitly* try out both possible interpretations of ***sense*** as...

> 2a: ***A [shared] feeling of** mutual interaction distinguishes the members of a group from a mere aggregation of individuals.*

...and...

> 2b: ***The meaning [of]** "mutual interaction" distinguishes the members of a group from a mere aggregation of individuals.*

Where I think 2b is nonsense.

---

<sup>1</sup> This is the "existential it" as in ***It's raining***. It doesn't refer to a specific ***thing***, any more than ***there*** in ***There's nothing more to say*** refers to a specific ***place***.